# VBA Excel: call a macro on close but not from the Workbook_BeforeClose function?

Tags: excel, vba

Simply put chaps I want to call a macro just before a workbook closes. You may say why not just put it into the ThisWorkbook section? The reason is that I am uploading a code module via VBA when the book is initially created. So there are basically two solution to this I just cannot figure it out

1. Call a sub based in a standard module before the close of the book
2. Find a way to upload with a VBA procedure a code sub into the ThisWorkbook section when the book is created

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Gary that it's probably best to use templates for this, but in any case here is an example of using VBA to add code to an existing VBModule, and to add a new standard module with code.

Obviously, the more complicated are the procedure's you're trying to add, the more difficult it will be to do this by building the strings in the procedure. You can add modules from file (assuming you've exported them -- which you can also do via VBA...) or you can also copy from existing modules in open workbooks, etc.  For how to do these things, please refer to the link provided below.

**NOTE** You will need to enable the application to Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model (File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings > Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model)

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddWorkbookWithCode()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add

AddVBCodeToWorkbook wb

End Sub
Sub AddVBCodeToWorkbook(wb As Workbook)
Dim procString$

procString = "Sub Workbook_BeforeClose()"
procString = procString & vbCrLf & vbTab & "On Error Resume Next"
procString = procString & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Call SayGoodby"
procString = procString & vbCrLf & "End Sub"

'## Insert some code to ThisWorkbook module:
With wb.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    .CodeModule.AddFromString procString
End With

'## Add a new standard module and insert some code there, too:
procString = "Public Sub SayGoodby()"
procString = procString & vbCrLf & vbTab & "MsgBox ""Goodby!"""
procString = procString & vbCrLf & "End Sub"

With wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    .Name = "Module1"
    .CodeModule.AddFromString procString
End With



End Sub
```

**[HERE](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.htm)** is some good reference material on programming the VBE.

Comment: Can you add a VBComponent? Such as a module or class with a similar process?

Comment: @CodeCamper Yes. Please refer to the link I provided earlier.

Comment: a ok - I get it - yer writting strings is not great however it will do - thank man - hey also the code need a tweek

Comment: Right. It's not great, but it will work. What tweak do you need?

Comment: oh sorry though I had posted this - so take you exact code and add Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(cancel as boolean) - and this is good - cheers David!

Answer (score 3):

Say at run-time we insert a module and in that module place a **Public** sub:

[image]

Then in the workbook code area:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call SayGoodby
End Sub
```

Comment: But how would you insert this code into a new workbook created with VBA?

Comment: @CodeCamper probably best not to hijack someone else's answer/question. If you have your own question, ask your own question :)  You will need to read up about programming the VBE, start [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.htm) :)

Comment: Rather than creating a totally new workbook, open a partially complete template with the workbook code already in place....then use VBA to insert the module & public sub

Comment: @DavidZemens Look at his #2 point, isn't that what he is asking for? I will ask a different question but it will be different from this one or what I asked in the comments. How do you insert the module into another workbook?

Comment: @CodeCamper  I am offering **Option#3**

Comment: Zemens is correct - basically how do I get the Call into the Workbook_BeforeClose event with an upload?